# Unable to login with an SSH key

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, ssh, login

I am trying to login with an SSH key on Ubuntu but the problem is that, at login time, I am asked to enter the password instead of a passphrase key. I setup permission, generated a key multiple times, checked the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

auth.log

```
ubuntu sshd[857]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
ubuntu sshd[857]: Connection from 192.168.1.x port 62310 on 192.168.1.x port 22
```

ubuntu:~$ ls -lar

```
drwx------   2 uadmin uadmin    .ssh
-rw-------  1  uadmin uadmin .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Please help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the first glanse, your problem is obvious:

1) You are missing a private RSA (or DSA) key. Usually it is named id_rsa.
   To generate a pair of keys use ssh-keygen. 
   A pharaphrase may be empty if you want to login without entering each time.

2) On remote host you must use a complimentary public RSA/DSA key, placed in ~/.ssh folder. Usually it is named id_rsa.pub.
   You may use ssh-copy-id tool.

In some rare cases, if server was configured specifically, you may need to check permissions of of $HOME and .ssh folders, and files located there. But, IMHO, it is an another story.

Best regards,
Vitaly

Comment: I've generate new key pair and set permission and login with private key but still getting same error and also not get error like Server refuse key,passphase etc,,, like that.

Comment: 1) Do you have another server to check the behaviour?
2) I would give a try to connect to another user account on the same machine. Just create a test account, set password, make sure you are able to login, then register a public key of your main account by ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub test@localhost command, then try to use SSH to login as a test account user.
3) If nothing helps, just show us the output of the following command: ssh -vv login@host 
Good luck!

Comment: Yes it's working in another machine!